# Identifying Impersonation Suspension Reason In App Publishing

Tags: android, google-play

I've uploaded my first Android application to Google Play yesterday, and was really excited for my app to finally be on out there.

But my application got **suspended for impersonation**. I obviously didn't get any more information about what I infringed specifically, and I'm unsure what I should change in order for the app to be accepted (more likely, resend as a different app name).

Before you could help me you'll need to know some information on the app itself. So I basically made a companion app for a video game. I called the application "Horadrim Companion", and it's supposed help players for playing Diablo 3. Naturally, I'm using elements from this game in the app.

**So, my main question is why did I get the impersonation suspension?**

I can think of several options, please help me figure out what of those could be the issue:

- I didn't write "This app is unofficial" in the description, which I've seen several other apps do. This might be the sole reason, but I'm not enough experienced to make this assumption.
- I took the logo out of the game lore. Which in itself should be borderline legit, but I've seen other apps do the same, so I assumed it's fine.
- The app name. I dont think I've hit a sweet spot with the name or anything, and I dont think it was any of the factors for the bans.
- In-app design? I've seen other apps use design elements from Blizzard Entertainment and\or Diablo 3 design elements themselves. Could this be another possible reason? Sounds more like copy right infringement if anything, and not impersonation.

So I'm not sure which, of the above are critical for the impersonation policy or not.
I'd really like your help, you could make one developer a happy man. I'm really afraid the account will be terminated.

I'd really liked your suggestions!

Comment: read these  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2986097?hl=en

Comment: Hey, I've read those comments, but I'm still not sure what's the actual problem is. Since I really didn't try to impersonate Blizzard, even gave 'em full credits in the description.

Comment: ask support team they provide you reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you receive an email from 
Google Play Support  with `REASON FOR REMOVAL: Violation of the spam provisions of the Content Policy. Please refer to the keyword spam policy help article for more information.`

`Your title and/or description attempts to impersonate or leverage another popular product without permission. Please remove all such references. Do not use irrelevant, misleading, or excessive keywords in apps descriptions, titles, or metadata.`

If you received no such notification, you should try submitting an appeal your app removal/suspension from Google Play using the form in the link below:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/appappeals

It is most likely that the reason for suspension is one from the list of options in your post, but usually it is explicitly highlighted by Google in their email under the section 'REASON FOR REMOVAL'

The link below lists more such reasons for removal due to trademark infringement of a third party IP:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2986098?hl=en&ref_topic=2985713

It is unlikely that your account itself will be terminated, unless you are identified by Google as a repeat offender.

Comment: I've recieved the following paragraph:REASON FOR SUSPENSION:Violation of the impersonation or deceptive behavior provisions of the Content Policy. Please refer to the impersonation policy help article for more information.

If you are authorized to publish on behalf of the original content or brand owner, please contact us via the Google Play Developer Help Center and attach verifiable and accepted proof of permission.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with suspended app publishing because of impersonation.

I solved this by buying/registering the domain name I used as my app package name. I also added my developer email in the company details section of my keystore while signing the apk for release. After doing this my second attempt at publishing was a success. 
It becomes easier if you actually own the domain of the package name you wanna use.
I think basically the algorithm used for verifying the originality of our apps is just too strict. So we have to also play our part and go the extra mile to show that we are legit.

Hope someone can relate to this.

All the best.

Comment: `It becomes easier if you actually own the domain of the package name you wanna use` Can you please give an example?

Comment: If your app's  applicationId or package name is for example "com.myappname" then I suggest you can go buy and own the domain name "myappname.com" and add it to your app's play store listing.

Answer (score 0):

"*I took the logo out of the game lore*"
It's not your resource so you violate intellectual property

"*The app name*"
You can't use a trademark word

Answer (score 0):

"I've seen other apps use design elements from Blizzard Entertainment"
Those apps must've been released years ago. Now, the SQA team is really strict about rule.
I mean, if u search "One Piece" or "Naruto" there are a lot of apps that doubtfully has a license.